# HttpClient not resolved upon upgrade of AWS SDK from V1 to V2

Tags: java, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-java-2.0

My Java application interacts with AWS services using the AWS SDK for Java, Version 1. I'm modifying it to use Version 2.

To upgrade to V2, I replaced the V1 S3 dependency, `amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:1.11.637`, with the V2 one, `software.amazon.awssdk:s3:2.7.1`, in my pom. And to keep the AWS SDK classes working in the code, I changed the import namespaces, from `com.amazonaws` to `software.amazon.awssdk`.

However, my code also uses a bunch of apache http imports, such as `org.apache.http.client.HttpClient` and `...ssl.SSLContexts`. These were provided by AWS SDK Version 1, but apparently not with Version 2. Thus, upgrading the AWS S3 dependency resulted in all the *org.apache.http* imports no longer resolving.

Is there an easy way to resolve this? Did those apache http classes (HttpResponse, HttpClient, SSLContexts, etc.) get moved to somewhere else in V2 of the AWS SDK for Java? I haven't found specific guidance on this in the AWS SDK docs.